# Pandas - Grouping columns based on other columns and tagging them into new column

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which I want to group based on the value of another column in the same data frame.

For example:

The Parent_ID and Child ID are linked and defines who is related to who in a hierarchical tree.

The dataframe looks like (input from a csv file)

```
No  Name    ID  Parent_Id
1   Tom     211 111
2   Galie   209 111
3   Remo    200 101
4   Carmen  212 121
5   Alfred  111 191
6   Marvela 101 111
7   Armin   234 101
8   Boris   454 109
9   Katya   109 323
```

I would like to group this data frame based on the ID and Parent_ID in the below grouping, and generate CSV files out of this based on the top level parent. I.e, Alfred.csv, Carmen.csv (will have only its own entry, ice line #4) , Katya.csv using the to_csv() function.

```
Alfred
  |_ Galie
   _ Tom
   _ Marvela
       |_ Remo
        _ Armin
Carmen
Katya
  |_ Boris
```

And, I want to create a new column in the same data frame, that will have a tag indicating the hierarchy. Like:

```
No  Name    ID  Parent_Id   Tag
1   Tom     211 111     Alfred
2   Galie   209 111     Alfred
3   Remo    200 101     Marvela, Alfred
4   Carmen  212 121 
5   Alfred  111 191 
6   Marvela 101 111     Alfred
7   Armin   234 101     Marvela, Alfred
8   Boris   454 109     Katya
9   Katya   109 323
```

Note that the names can repeat, but the ID will be unique.

Kindly let me know how to achieve this using pandas. I tried out groupby() but seems a little complicated and not getting what I intend. There should be one file for each parent, and the child records in the parent file. 
If a child has other child (like marvel), it qualifies to have its own csv file.

And the final output would be

```
Alfred.csv - All records matching Galie, Tom, Marvela
Marvela.csv - All records matching Remo, Armin
Carmen.csv - Only record matching carmen (row)
Katya.csv - all records matching katya, boris
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your dataframe as a dictionary:

```
mydf = ({"No":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"Name":["Tom","Galie","Remo","Carmen","Alfred","Marvela","Armin","Boris","Katya"],
        "ID":[211,209,200,212,111,101,234,454,109],"Parent_Id":[111,111,101,121,191,111,101,109,323]})
df = pd.DataFrame(mydf)
```

Then, I identify the `Parent_Id` from each row. Finally stored them into new column:

```
tag = []
for z in df['Parent_Id']:
    try:
        tag.append(df.query('ID==%s'%z)['Name'].item())
    except:
        tag.append('')
df['Tag'] = tag
```

To filter the dataframe based on a value in column `Tag`, e.g. `Alfred`:

```
df[df['Tag'].str.match('Alfred')]
```

Then save it in a `csv` file. Repeat for other values. Alternatively, if you have a large number of names in column `Tag`, then use `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Yusufun. I clarified the question a little more.

Comment: You can try `df[df['Tag'].str.match('Alfred')]` for rows contain `Alfred` in column `Tag`. Repeat for other values.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to avoid a for loop. The csv input I am dealing with would be 100s of 1000s of lines. The part I am very interested in is converting my input csv into multiple output csvs outlined above.